# How to append values to keys in python dictionary based on dataframe rows with repeated key-value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I have ecommerce data with rows of key-value pairs, like:

```
row1: "ideal for":"women", "color":"blue"
row2: "ideal for": "women", "color":"red"
row3: "ideal for": "men", "color":"blue"
```

What I need is to create a new dictionary that will include the keys and arrays of the relevant values, e.g.:

```
{"ideal for": ["women","men"], "color": ["red", "blue"]}
```

When I try to append values to keys in the new dictionary, I can't seem to figure out to do it in the way so that the values do not repeat.

```
df.apply(lambda row: prep_text(row['product_specifications']), axis=1)
tag_info = df['product_specifications']
tag_info.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
tag_info.dropna(inplace=True)
tags_dict = dict()
for row in tag_info:
     for key, value in row.items():
         if key not in tags_dict:
             tags_dict[key] = [value]
         elif value not in tags_dict.values():
             tags_dict[key].append(value)
```

Right now, I get a new dictionary that looks like this:

```
{"ideal for": ["women","women","men"], "color":["blue", "red", "blue"]}
```

What do I have to do so that the values do not repeat?

Comment: The above is not a valid dictionary, in a dictionary a key maps to a value.

Comment: What exactly is your first code block?

Comment: The dictionary I get maps keys to values which are lists of items. I corrected the code above.

Comment: @timgeb I added it now

Comment: Why not just use an `if` statement inside your `elif` statement? The nested `if` statement would check whether the value is already in your list; if it is, then you don't append to your list. Otherwise, you append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements of tags_dict.values() are *Lists* of strings, not strings. You should check

```
 elif value not in tags_dict[key]:
     tags_dict[key].append(value)
```

Or you can use *Set* instead of *List* as a values for the tags_dict. *Set* can include only one copy of every value, so if you add second copy of the same value it'll just ignore it. But values in *Set* are unordered.

```
  if key not in tags_dict:
      tags_dict[key] = {value}
  else:
      tags_dict[key].add(value)
```

Comment: Thank you, this clarified it for me perfectly.